# Aurelia Webpack Router Error when using <form> Element in View

Tags: typescript, webpack, aurelia

so im relatively new to working with Aurelia.io and i have stumbled upon an error.
Since i have implemented a router in my application, once i define a `<form>` element in my View i get the following errorcode in my browser:

```
ERROR [app-router] Error: Error invoking Form. Check the inner error for details.
------------------------------------------------
Inner Error:
Message: too much recursion
Inner Error Stack:
Container.prototype._get@webpack-internal:///3U8n:532:41
Container.prototype._get@webpack-internal:///3U8n:538:32
Container.prototype._get@webpack-internal:///3U8n:538:32
Container.prototype._get@webpack-internal:///3U8n:538:32
```

my Form.html looks like this:

```
   <div id="formcontainer">

      <form>

        <!--Vorname-->   
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="input-data">
              <input type="text" value.bind="Applicant.Name & validate" required>
              <div class="underline"></div>
              <label>Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Nachname-->   
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="input-data">
              <input type="text" required>
              <div class="underline"></div>
              <label>Family Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </form>
   </div>
```

without the `<form>` element everything works fine.

The Form.html is shown in my app.html via routing:

```
<template>
  
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

And my app.ts with the router config looks like this:

```
export class App {
  router: any;

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'Form'],       name: 'Form', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('Form/Form') ,title: 'ApplicationProcess' },
      { route: 'Confirmation',       name: 'Confirmation', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('Confirmation/Confirmation') ,title: 'Sending Confirmed' }
    ]);
  }
```

}

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have something in your Form.js that is being triggered by a change event or something loading. This wouldn't cause errors normally.

Do you mind posting a codepen or something we can go off of?

A too much recursion error happens when a JS function is firing off recursively too many times.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Too_much_recursion